# iOS 5.0 Simulator always quits: "The simulated application quit"

Tags: ios5, osx-lion, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 4.2 final Build 4D199 from the Mac App Store. When I want to start any application in the iOS 5 simulator it quits telling me that i can Quit, Switch SDK or Relaunch. I downloaded additionally the 4.3 SDK/Simulator and there it works. I used the builts for iOS 5 during beta but finally removed every other developer installation using uninstall-devtools in /Developer/Library but it didn't solve the problem.

Console says:

---

```
Process:         SpringBoard [4764]
Path:            /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:      SpringBoard
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  iPhone Simulator [4748]

Date/Time:       2011-10-31 14:45:25.541 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.2 (11C74)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000a, 0x000000000bf33000

VM Regions Near 0xbf33000:
__LINKEDIT             000000000bf29000-000000000bf33000 [   40K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
--> mapped file            000000000bf33000-000000000bf42000 [   60K] r--/r-x SM=PRV  /Network/*/*.cpbitmap
__TEXT                 000000000bf42000-000000000bf8f000 [  308K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 272, iPhone OS 5.0 (iPhone/9A334)
```

---

```
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   QuartzCore                    0x01ce06b5 void CA::OGL::SW::image_sampler<CA::OGL::SW::Format::ARGB8_Host, false, false, false, false>(CA::OGL::SW::SamplerData const*, unsigned int, unsigned int*) + 64
1   QuartzCore                    0x01cda0fa CA::OGL::SW::sample_texture(CA::OGL::SW::Texture const*, int, unsigned int, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned int*) + 686
2   QuartzCore                    0x01cdbc4b CA::OGL::SW::scanline(CA::OGL::SW::ScanState const*, int, int, int, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex*, CA::OGL::SW::Poly::Vertex const*, unsigned int) + 1172
3   QuartzCore                    0x01cdd3bd CA::OGL::SW::scan_convert_thread(void*, void*) + 3009
4   QuartzCore                    0x01cff92f CA::DispatchGroup::dispatch(bool) + 191
5   QuartzCore                    0x01cff969 CA::DispatchGroup::callback_1(void*) + 25
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x047944e6 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 284
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x9930db24 _pthread_wqthread + 346
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x9930f6fe start_wqthread + 30
```

Comment: it also appears, if I create a new project for iOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that occurred on the simulator in 4.3 and 5.0. I was finally able to squash it by removing an unnecessary call to `[self setNeedsDisplay]` in the `setFrame` selector of a subclass of UIView that was set up to return a `CATiledLayer` in response to its class method `+(Class)layerClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem in CATiledLayer where the call of the static method (Class)layerClass. and specifically in the initialization function where you set the size of the tileSize. make sure it's not 0;

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads
Make sure your target SDK you have set in your project is installed in Xcode.